# add linked list java

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, addition

I need to add an "user" into a linked list, and the linked list is a part of a linked list.

```
public void shibutz(user a){

    this.serverList(this.placeInServerList(a.code)).add(a);
```

server list is the linked list of linked lists.
these are the classes this line uses:

```
public int placeInServerList(String code){
    if (this.serverList.contains(code)){
        return indentifyCode(code);
    }
    return -42;
}
public int indentifyCode (String code){
    int counter=0;
    Group i= this.serverList.getFirst();
    while (this.serverList!=null){
        if (i.getCode()==code){
            return counter; }
        counter++;
        i=this.serverList.get(counter);
        return indentifyCode (code);
    }
    return -42;}
```

group is a linked list.
now, I need help with the first code part. I don't understand what Eclipse wants from me. none of the solutions it's giving me are relative. thanks!!!

Comment: What's the question...? What the code does vs what do you want it to do?

Comment: You need to use `equals` in order to compare Strings properly. This line of code ` if (i.getCode()==code){` should be replaced with `i.getCode().equals(code)`   because `code`  is a `String` `public int indentifyCode (String code)`

Answer (score 0):

Reading this line :

```
Group i = this.serverList.getFirst()
```

I assume that `serverList` is a `LinkedList<Group>`.

Hence, this is invalid :

```
public int placeInServerList(String code){
  //code is a String, not a Group
  if (this.serverList.contains(code))
```

As `serverList` is a `LinkedList<Group>`, the method that you can call is `serverList.contains(Group)`. The method`serverList.contains(String)` does not exist.